# NTP Slew vs Step (Jump) Mode

Tags: ntp

What is the NTP slew mode?

When should it be enabled?

How is it different from NTP Step mode?

Can slew work when system clock steps backwards?

Does slow operation differ based on the underlying operating system?

If there are OS-based differences, then AIX OS is my main concern.

Thanks,